# Is something wrong in the while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have a store_credits_orders table

[image]

and orders table.

[image]

The output that I want is similar to this but based on `Store Credit Order Date and Time` and `Store Order Date and Time`:

[image]

The code that I have tried so far:

```
<?php
$table = '';
$queryToGetStoreCredit = "SELECT * FROM store_credits_orders WHERE SCO_CustEmailAdd = '".$_SESSION["Customer"]["email"]."'";
$validate->Query($queryToGetStoreCredit);
if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
    while ($rows_sco = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
        $used = $i = 0;
        $table .= '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$rows_sco["SCO_OrderCode"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>--</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$rows_sco["SCO_OrderDate"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>--</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$rows_sco["SCO_Purchase_Amount"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$rows_sco["SCO_Credit_Alloted"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$used.'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.( $rows_sco["SCO_Credit_Alloted"] - $used ).'</td>';
        $table .= '</tr>';

        $validate2 = new Validation();
        $queryToGetOrder = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE CustEmailAdd = '".$rows_sco["SCO_CustEmailAdd"]."'";
        $validate2->Query($queryToGetOrder);
        while ($row = $validate2->FetchAllDatas()) {
            $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<td>--</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'.$row["OrderCode"].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td>--</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'.$row["OrderDate"].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td>--</td>';
            $table .= '<td>--</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'.$row["AppliedCredits"].'</td>';
            $table .= '<td>'.($rows_sco["SCO_Credit_Alloted"] - $row["AppliedCredits"]).'</td>';
            $table .= '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to achieve is, whenever there is a purchase of store_credits, the information will get inserted in the `store_credits_orders` table. Now when the same user comes, places an order and redeems the store_credits (less than equal to, he has in his account), there will be no update in the database other than insertion in the orders table.

But when the user logs in, he should be able to see when he has purchased the store_credits and/or when he has redeemed the store_credits. All these events should be ordered by whichever event happens first, irrespective of purchase or redeem.

Comment: where is your update query?Also your question is bit unclear?

Comment: which update query ? And for what ?

Comment: You asked "I need to update the store credits as when it is redeemed and / or purchased."? that one i am asking

Comment: That needs to be done at the run time... No queries will be executed for that..

Comment: When "redeemed and / or purchased" is happen at that time you have to execute query to update your store credits.? Am i right?

Comment: Why is it so ?? Can't I deduct or add `store_credits` at the run time ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73392/discussion-between-anant-kumar-singh-and-user3514160).

Comment: Please help me out, as I am scratching my head since 2 days to solve this.

Comment: You want output from the two tables put in one list then ordered by date and time? Your code does not do that. If you want to use your current code then the query results should go into one array and then sort that array by date/time. Then output from that array. The other way is to join (or union) the two tables with SQL with an 'order by' clause and then output it with php.

Comment: @RyanVincent Sir, I am new to all this, kindly help me with the code.

Comment: What i will suggest is: use your favorite  internet search engine and do: _php extract data from two tables and sort it_. It returns a list of 'stackoverflow questions and answers' that will help you to proceed.

Comment: Nothing has helped me, Can anyone please help me out... I am really in need of the solution..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical error to display mysql table data, assistance needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139098/logical-error-to-display-mysql-table-data-assistance-needed)

Comment: It appears you've abandoned your previous identical question and asked it again. This isn't recommended, but if you really must ask it again (for example to tackle it from a different angle) then it is a good idea to make a note on the previous one, say in a comment. That way people reading your old question won't waste their time if it is already solved here.

Comment: @halfer Thank you Sir for informing about this. I was not knowing about it all. I'll make sure this won't happen next time.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to @user3514160 and I got clarity what he want's to have. Basically data gets inserted correctly. Only thing he wants is to show data in correct way.

Your **query** should look like this

```
(SELECT
  SCO_Id,
  SCO_OrderCode,
  SCO_CustEmailAdd,
  SCO_Purchase_Amount,
  SCO_Credit_Alloted,
  SCO_OrderDate,
  SCO_OrderIP,
  null AS OrderId,
  null AS OrderCode,
  null AS CustEmailAdd,
  null AS AppliedCredits,
  null AS OrderDate,
  'store_credits_orders' AS tableName
FROM `store_credits_orders` AS credits_orders WHERE `SCO_CustEmailAdd` = '".$_SESSION["Customer"]["email"]."')
UNION
(SELECT
  OrderId,
  OrderCode,
  CustEmailAdd,
  AppliedCredits,
  OrderDate
  null AS SCO_Id,
  null AS SCO_OrderCode,
  null AS SCO_CustEmailAdd,
  null AS SCO_Purchase_Amount,
  null AS SCO_Credit_Alloted,
  OrderDate AS SCO_OrderDate,
  null AS SCO_OrderIP,
  'store_orders' AS tableName
FROM `store_orders` AS orders WHERE `SCO_CustEmailAdd` = '".$_SESSION["Customer"]["email"]."')
ORDER BY `SCO_OrderDate` ASC
```

This is needed to get all rows in one result. We accomplish this with [MySQL UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

UNION needs both tables to have same amount of columns with same names. This is why we add empty columns with `null AS columnName`.

And **PHP** with query

```
<?php
$table = '<table>';

// Query to get all rows from both tables
$queryToGetStoreCredit = 
"(SELECT
  SCO_Id,
  SCO_OrderCode,
  SCO_CustEmailAdd,
  SCO_Purchase_Amount,
  SCO_Credit_Alloted,
  SCO_OrderDate,
  SCO_OrderIP,
  null AS OrderId,
  null AS OrderCode,
  null AS CustEmailAdd,
  null AS AppliedCredits,
  null AS OrderDate,
  'store_credits_orders' AS tableName
FROM `store_credits_orders` AS credits_orders WHERE `SCO_CustEmailAdd` = '".$_SESSION["Customer"]["email"]."')
UNION
(SELECT
  OrderId,
  OrderCode,
  CustEmailAdd,
  AppliedCredits,
  OrderDate
  null AS SCO_Id,
  null AS SCO_OrderCode,
  null AS SCO_CustEmailAdd,
  null AS SCO_Purchase_Amount,
  null AS SCO_Credit_Alloted,
  OrderDate AS SCO_OrderDate,
  null AS SCO_OrderIP,
  'store_orders' AS tableName
FROM `store_orders` AS orders WHERE `SCO_CustEmailAdd` = '".$_SESSION["Customer"]["email"]."')
ORDER BY `SCO_OrderDate` ASC";

$validate->Query($queryToGetStoreCredit);
if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
    // Starting balance. This could be some other number, for example if viewing some certain period of orders etc.
    $balance = 0;
    while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {

        // Add to balance
        if($row['tableName'] == 'store_credits_orders' && (int)$row['SCO_Credit_Alloted'] > 0){
          $balance += (int)$row['SCO_Credit_Alloted']
        }
        // Remove from balance
        else if($row['tableName'] == 'store_orders' && (int)$row['AppliedCredits'] > 0){
          $balance -= (int)$row['AppliedCredits'];
        }

        $table .= '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row["SCO_OrderCode"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row["OrderCode"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.(($row['tableName'] == 'store_credits_orders') ? $row["SCO_OrderDate"] : '').'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row["OrderDate"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row["SCO_Purchase_Amount"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row["SCO_Credit_Alloted"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$row["AppliedCredits"].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td>'.$balance.'</td>';
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
}

$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
?>
```

Let me know, if there is some problems.

Comment: It is always a good idea to explicitly state the returned columns in an sql union rather tha use '*' (return all columns). The reason is that if a new column is added to either table then the query will fail. Also, you are relying on appropriate columns being in the same order in both tables.

Comment: Yes, edited my answer. @RyanVincent, what do you mean about relying on same ordering of columns?

Comment: If we set null for last two columns of second query, `SCO_Credit_Alloted` will get value of `OrderDate`, what we don't want. Currently all column names are preserved.